# in c# how to insert different types(combobox,TimeDataPicker,..) into Access Databse

Tags: c#

i am trying to insert (textbox, combobox , Datatimepicker)
 To access Database but i got this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Here is my code:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
         connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
         command.CommandText = 
             "insert into Hoteldb (Guest Full Name,  Date-Birth,  Room Numb,  Room Type,Check In Date,Check Out Date,No-Of-Adults,No-Of-Child,Advance Payment,Total Balance ) values(' " 
             + this.textBox1.Text + " ', '" + this.dbp.Text + " '  ,' " + this.textBox2.Text + " ' , '" + this.comboBox1.Text + "',  '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker2.Text +
           "'  ,'" + this.textBox5.Text + " ','" + this.textBox6.Text + " ',' " + this.textBox3.Text + " ',' " + this.textBox4.Text + " ') ";


        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Geust Check-in");

             connection.Close();


    }
```

what is the right way that can i through it  insert the data correctly

Comment: First off, use bound parameters, not literals.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if your column names contain spaces, they have to be wrapped in `[]` in MS Access.

Comment: yes , i have used a bound parameters 
but the problem has not solved

Comment: You are now vulnerable to sql injection (or at least errors) in case a mister `O'Brien` wants to check into your hotel. The single quote in the name will make your query go bad because you do not escape quotes anywhere. Yet another reason to use Query Parameters. Also as mentioned, column names that contain spaces or other special characters need special treatment.

Comment: I have changed them and the error is still

Comment: any other suggestions to fix the problem ??